# Splitting column values into multiple rows and column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a problem with pandas. The input data is a single column :

```
 MixedColumn    
-------------
 20_5, 20_5**1   
 20_7**9    
 20_4, 40_4, 15_4**2
```

And what I want to split and transform it into something like this :

```
Col1   Col2   
--------------
 20_5    1         
 20_5    1           
 20_7    9       
 20_4    2  
 40_4    2
 15_4    2
```

The logic is split each row item **(20_5, 20_5)** based on comma (if present) and place them in next row of same column (Col1). As well as split each row item **(**1)** based on ** and associate them with individual values in a separate column (Col2).

Sorry if this is a noob question. Any hints will surely help me out. Thanks and wish you all a happy holiday.

Comment: Is mixedcolumn of dtype object?

Comment: Yup. Its object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First split on `**` to get `Col2` with [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and `expand=True`.

Then we use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to make a new row for each element to create `Col1`:

*note: this requires `pandas >= 0.25.0`*

```
df[['Col1', 'Col2']] = df['MixedColumn'].str.split('\*\*', expand=True)

df = df.assign(Col1=df['Col1'].str.split(', ')).explode('Col1').drop(columns='MixedColumn')

   Col1 Col2
0  20_5    1
0  20_5    1
1  20_7    9
2  20_4    2
2  40_4    2
2  15_4    2
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"mixed_column": ["20_5, 20_5**1", "20_7**9", "20_4, 40_4, 15_4**2"]})
df_split = df.mixed_column.str.rsplit("**").apply(pd.Series)
df_split[0] = df_split.apply(lambda x: x[0].split(", "), axis=1)
df_split = df_split.explode(0)
```

which gives you

```
      0  1
0  20_5  1
0  20_5  1
1  20_7  9
2  20_4  2
2  40_4  2
2  15_4  2
```